# Angular 6 .net Web Api No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header Error

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am developing .net Core Web Api with Vs Code with Angular 6, Vs Studio.
The error is as follows;
- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
- No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http: // localhost: 4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response was HTTP status code 500.

```
// I added to Startup.cs;
ConfigureServices === >>> services.AddCors ();
Configure === >>>> app.UseCors (bldr => bldr.WithOrigins ("http: // 
localhost: 4200") .WithMethods ("GET", "POST"). AllowAnyHeader ());
```

The problem is that; The problem is resolved in the get method, the data is retrieved but it does not work in the post method. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try ` app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);` as @Anton suggested in the answer?

Comment: I tried but not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this, the [dotnet core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1)
talks about how to handle CORS.

This tends to be an issue only during development so this is my preferred method to solving this issue.

Add CORS rule to the services which allows everything during development

```
if (_env.IsDevelopment())
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                  p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowCredentials());
    });
}
```

Then add the created rule to the Application Builder:

```
if (_env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");
}
```

Alternatevely

There is also a [CORS browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/jioikioepegflmdnbocfhgmpmopmjkim?hl=en) available for Google Chrome, I am not sure about other browsers.

This is my goto when I don't want to meddle with the request/response headers and is a quick fix for when this issue occurs with other projects not just .net core.

A word of warning though, sometimes this plugin doesn't work.

Comment: I tried but not. 

ANGULAR;
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
options.responseType = ResponseContentType.Blob;
let body = JSON.stringify(sorguParametreleri);
return this.http.post(this.apiURL + "/AGranter/DownloadReport", body, options).map((response: any) => {

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that `services.AddCors()` must come before `services.AddMvc()` and the same with `app.UseCors()` and `app.UseMvc()`.